# Pre-school or preschool?

Tags: spelling, hyphens

When I check my various dictionaries (Longman; Cambridge; Merriam-Webster and a bilingual dictionary), preschool is spelt without a hyphen. Still, when I google it, I get a fair number of hits for both spellings. So, is the spelling with a hyphen just a common misspelling, or are both correct?

Thank you!

Comment: The use (or not) of a hyphen in compound words is not a misspelling, just a stylistic choice.

Comment: For any compound word? Even a total neologism?

Comment: "I get a fair number of hits for both spellings."  There is your answer.  Both are accepted.

Comment: @JamesK :) In analogy with "Eat shit, millions of flies can't be wrong"? ;) ;) ;) Seriously though, just because something gets a lot of hits on Google, it doesn't mean it's correct, right? For instance, in my language, people commonly misspell the word for 'felt', and if you Google the equivalent of 'I have felt', you get 147 hits with the word for 'felt' misspelt, whereas you only get 100 hits where it's spelt the correct way. So...

Comment: The difference is that "correct" spelling is defined by the usage of writers of English. Of course you need to look at high quality sources. Dictionaries are good because they do the searching of high quality sources for you.  But the only meaning of "correct spelling" is "the way that it is usually spelled"

Comment: @JamesK Yes, in a sense you're right of course, although you're oversimplifying quite a bit. Which is obviously understandable – the complex processes involved in language development/changing conventions can't really be summed up in a short comment like this :) Either way, I'm grateful for your input :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As James K says [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/292033/139882), the more common the spelling is, the more likely it gets merged into a single word. So in that sense both are correct, but the whole word is more modern.

See also what [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/hyphens) has to say about hyphens.

Comment: Thank you so much! This was really useful!!